# How to increase "screen buffer" when connected to the machine via SSH?

Tags: openssh, scrolling, sshd, gnu-screen

TLDR: I want to see a lot more of my screen via scrolling back when the command/script (e.g. ls -la /etc) displays results that doesn't fit in 1 screen.

---

If you check the screenshot below, it doesn't show the files/folders before iproute2 if I scroll back up using the scroll bars.

If I ran the ran same command on a RedHat box, I can definitely see all the files/folders before "iproute2" if I scroll back up.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: You probably need to set up screen and your terminal emulator to understand what scrolling via the scrollbar is.

Comment: which ubuntu config is this associated with? As I said, Redhat/FreeBSD works fine out o the box.

Comment: Your `~/.screenrc`, presumably. And I have never seen screen work "fine" out of the box. Certainly not with scrolling, certainly not on RHEL.